# Overlap section with next section using scroll

Tags: jquery, css

First section has fixed position.
The next section should smoothly overlap the first(fixed section) after user scroll mouse weel.
But the full page scroll should not scrolling before the first section target top and overlap the full first section. And this is issue. I can't to turn off the scroll for full page.

As you can see the scroll work but not like it should.

```js
$('#first-section').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
  if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 5 > 0) {
    console.log('up')
  } else {
    $('#sections-wrapp').addClass('active');
    setTimeout(function() { 
      $('body').removeClass('home_scroll');
    }, 500);
    setTimeout(function() { 
      $('#wrapper').removeClass('false_scroll');
    }, 500);

  }
});

$('#overlay-section').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
  if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 1 > 0) {
    $('body').addClass('home_scroll');
    $('#sections-wrapp').removeClass('active')
    $('#wrapper').addClass('false_scroll');
    $('#intro').removeClass('active');
  } else {

  }
});
```

```css
.slide-section-wrapper{
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.sections-wrapp{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100vh);
    -ms-transform: translateY(100vh);
    transform: translateY(100vh);
    -webkit-transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(.23,.6,.01,.22);
    -o-transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(.23,.6,.01,.22);
    transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(.23,.6,.01,.22);
    z-index: 4;
}
.sections-wrapp.active{
  transform: none
}
.overlay-section{
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

.slider-section{
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>overlapping section</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section id="first-section" class="slide-section-wrapper">

  </section>
  <div id="sections-wrapp" class="sections-wrapp">
    <section id="overlay-section" class="overlay-section"></section>
    <section id="slider-section" class="slider-section"></section>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Here is example of my goal: https://www.loom.com/share/3f10f9bef3c84b05acb155b570c1f3c4
the video for better understanding what I mean and have to do. The test on the video was creating with vue.js but I have to do this using jQuery or pure JavaScript.

Comment: You have a lot of deprecated and unused lines of code. Anyways, to prevent an Event from executing (in your case, you don't want the page scroll to execute), you need to use ```event.preventDefault()```. Put it in your scroll event listener function. Generally I would not suggest using a Vue tutorial for a pure js/jquery project. Very different API.

Comment: @Lalalena Thanks for the explanation, and suggestion for using event.preventDefault() method.